# i keep getting an error when I try to call a method into my main function

Tags: java

> the objective of this function is get the agent state for an agent in a call center environment

```
package avaya_connection;
```

public class Avaya_Connection {

```
     public void agentUpdate(Agent agentState)//checking agent state 
     {
        agentState.getAgentID();
          int previousAgentState = LucentAgent.UNKNOWN;/*the previous state 
          will by default be unknown*/

    if (agentState.getState() == previousAgentState)//getting the agent state
        return ;

    previousAgentState = agentState.getState();


    String msg = "AgentState: ";
    switch (previousAgentState) {//switch statement to find the current agent state

    case Agent.LOG_OUT:
        System.out.println("Agent is logged out");
        break;

    case Agent.READY://agent state returns ready
        System.out.println("Agent is ready");
        break;

    case Agent.NOT_READY://agent state returns not read
        System.out.println("Agent is not ready");
        break;

    case Agent.WORK_NOT_READY:
        System.out.println("Agent work not ready");
        break;

    case Agent.BUSY:
        System.out.println("Agent is busy");
        break;

    default:
        // Received an event which is not to be processed.

     }

     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {

             Avaya_Connection ac = new Avaya_Connection();
             ac.agentUpdate(agentState);/*calling the method of checking 
             agent states*/


     }
}
```

- List item

error returned is symbol can't be found and it wants a parm when its left blank

Comment: what is `ac` ? You don't declare it...

Comment: And what do you *believe* you're passing as an argument? You're meant to be supplying information to the method - it doesn't look like you've got that information.

Comment: Sorry i missed that part when i was copying the code but the ac is the object of the constructed class so its basically Avaya_Connection ac = new...

Comment: At least provide a [mcve] ... check my answer, the first step is OK but you still don't declare an `agentState`, just do it...

Comment: ive added more context

Answer (score 0):

To call a method of an instance, you first need to declare and instanciate it.

```
Avaya_Connection ac = new Avaya_Connection();
```

Same thing with the parameter

```
Agent agentState = new Agent();
```

Then you can call the method and pass the argument correctly.

```
ac.agentUpdate(agentState);
```

You can't call a method without an instance, unless it is static.

Answer (score -1):

You first need to declare and instantiate it.

```
Avaya_Connection ac = new Avaya_Connection();

Agent a = new Agent();
```

and then call your method as below.

```
ac.agentUpdate(a);
```

Comment: agent is abstract and cannot be instantiated

Comment: im sorry i cannot expose all of the code due to it being IP of my company